# Read-only web access to a read-write database in Neo4j 3.0

Tags: neo4j

There has been quite a few changes to the core of Neo4j in this new update, which is really exciting.

One thing that was lacking in previous Neo4j releases was the ability to let users use the web interface. Well, they could use it if you didn't mind them being able to delete everything, or you didn't mind making the whole database read-only to everyone, including yourself.

Is there a workaround now in 3.x? I see you've made some pretty awesome improvements to the web interface (which seem to have flown under the radar in all the conferences and YouTube videos) - however I can't let my users use any of this awesome because they might `match (n) detach delete (n)`.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to enterprise version or don't mind the AGPL license of neo4j-ha then you can create a read-only slave.

Have a look at neo4j [high availability documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha.html) for configuration.

In particular you want to have following properties set:

```
# Only allow read operations from this Neo4j instance. This mode still requires
# write access to the directory for lock purposes.
dbms.read_only=true
```

and

```
# Whether this instance should only participate as slave in cluster. If set to
# true, it will never be elected as master.
ha.slave_only=true
```

Comment: This is a good solution for people willing to stretch for the enterprise version, particularly because it means the database is not at risk from any of the security issues created by the webserver/etc that the read_only slave would have to run and expose publicly, It also works on versions of Neo before 3.0 -- however, i'm sure that other people finding this question in hopes of a simple solution will be upset if I mark the question as answered too early before a simpler/free solution is provided :) But great answer thanks frant!